# Spring Loading all JNDI Properties

Tags: xml, spring, tomcat, jndi

I have a spring application that uses tomcat as it's container. Tomcat's context.xml has the following entries:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/DB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="postgres" password=""
          url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
          driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
<Environment name="ws.url" type="java.lang.String" value="http://localhost:8088/" />
```

The resouce is loaded just fine using the following xml config:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/DB" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

But I tried loading the environment variable using the following xml config: (here I am trying to set ${url} to http://localhost:8088/" as set in the context.xml file)

```
<bean id="databaseprops" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="properties">
            <bean class="java.util.Properties">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="url">
                            <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:comp/env/ws.url"/>
                        </entry>
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

But I get the following error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [ws.url] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [ws.url].
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this issue, there were technically two problems.

The `NameNotFound` exception was being thrown because I was doing the silly mistake of using the wrong version of tomcat i.e. I input the above XML in the context.xml of a tomcat 7 instance but was running using tmocat 8 (I have multiple versions for testing purposes).

After I fixed that I got a new error were `${url}` was not being resolved. This I fixed by removing the bean `databaseprops` and only keeping the inner bean of type `java.util.Properties` and giving it an id, resulting in the following XML config:

```
<bean id="contextProperties" class="java.util.Properties">
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="url">
                <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:comp/env/ws.url"/>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Then I added the following xml config to tell Spring to use the above bean to resolve properties.

```
 <context:property-placeholder properties-ref="contextProperties"/>
```